# How to open a website in google chrome using webbrowser module

Tags: python, python-webbrowser, windows-11

I am trying to open a website from python in google chrome, but when I run this code -

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('youtube.com')
```

It opens Youtube in edge browser. Then I tried to change the default browser, but it still didn't work, so I ran this code:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.get('C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s').open('youtube.com')
```

But this code didn't give any output. So how can I open a website in google chrome using python.

Comment: Make sure, C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe is correct. If you have installed a 64 bit version it will be inside Program Files, not Program Files (x86).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import webbrowser 

url = "https://www.youtube.com/"
webbrowser.open(url)
```

I use `https://www.youtube.com/` instead of `youtube.com` and it will works :)

Comment: Yes it works for me too, thanks @arya sianati

Comment: Your welcome. Happy to help :)